# ¿Que tipo de datos es g->v[i]?

Tags: c++, struct, teoría-de-grafos

```
struct Graph {
    weightMatrix_t      v; //matriz de vertices de adyacencia
    size_t              nv; //numero de vertices
    size_t              ne; //numero de aristas
};
```

Con este grafo tengo lo siguiente:

```
g->v[i];
```

Si yo quiero asignar un nombre a eso, ¿que tipo de dato es?
Si lo pongo como puntero no me funciona. 
Me refiero a poner algo así:

```
GraphPtr = g->v[i];
g->v[i] = filas;
```

Espero que se entienda mi pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagino que el problema lo has sacado de [aqui](https://www.dlsi.ua.es/asignaturas/p2ir/practicas/p02.pdf)

`g->v` es de tipo `weightMatrix_t`. Como intentamos acceder a una posición de `g->v[i]`, se entiende que `weightMatrix_t` es una suerte de puntero o lista ... ¿Qué tipo es?  ni idea porque no has puesto la declaración del tipo. Así que asumiremos que he acertado acerca de los orígenes de tu código.

Según el documento, tenemos los siguientes tipos:

```
typedef double     weight_t;
typedef weight_t*  weightRow_t;
typedef weight_t** weightMatrix_t;
```

Así pues, `weightMatrix_t` es un puntero doble de tipo `weight_t`, un alias de `double`.

Eliminando alias tenemos:

```
struct Graph {
    double**            v; //matriz de vertices de adyacencia
    size_t              nv; //numero de vertices
    size_t              ne; //numero de aristas
};
```

Dado que `v` es un puntero doble de tipo `double`, `v[i]` es un puntero de tipo `double`

```
g->v[i] <-> double*
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres saber el nombre del tipo de un dato puedes usar el operador [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid):

```
const auto &id = typeid(g->v[i]);
```

El operador devuelve un objeto de tipo [`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) que contiene una función miembro llamada [`name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) que informa de el nombre del tipo que se obtuvo con el operador `typeid`.

Si lo usamos sobre [este código](https://tio.run/##RcrBCsIwDADQc/MVAS/rQNl5rf7IEIltGYEtLV16EPHbK568Pl4o5Rw2krX3E0vYWkzoOR9aE@03ABbFnVgGC28w7WBZUbnkR6Wa8Yoxt@eWxtGB@TM5AHNonOeQm6L3qK@SOA60THd7EdrTYH@nJm1VcHLw6f0L):

```
using tipo_raro = double**;
tipo_raro a;

std::cout << typeid(a[0]).name();
```

Vemos como retorno:

> ```
> Pd
> ```

Que es el nombre interno que el compilador otorga al tipo puntero (`P`) a `double` (`d`), esta manera de nombrar internamente los tipos se conoce como mutilar los nombres (*name mangling*).

Cada compilador mutila los nombres a su manera y ofrece a su vez una manera de desmutilarlos. En el caso del compilador que he usado en mi ejemplo, si se incluye la cabecera `<cxxabi.h>` se obtendrá acceso a la función `abi::__cxa_demangle` que puede [usarse así](https://tio.run/##RY7RasMwDEWfo68QHZSktCXPSdYfGSOotugEiR1sGVLKvj21O1hBAulydBCbZTnl3rYPcWZKlnEQHzUwzRd4Z2Zd6SrnnwuAOMWZxNUNPKBKUdwNVRY/BgoeP9H6dJ34cOihesfUA1TGu6hIST3uxWZU7wuLremr/W4yXsxRSVMsdFTbdcYnxWFAsWdHM9dNWXb5dFeG/FLXjaNZabQ8k7tNXP@TR2xftf9TNsUZWFNw2Pbwu21P):

```
using tipo_raro = double**;
tipo_raro a;

const auto &id = typeid(a[0]);
int status;

std::cout << id.name() << " = " << abi::__cxa_demangle(id.name(), 0, 0, &status);
```

El código anterior muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> Pd = double*
> ```

Podrías redactar una función para ayudarte en esto, pero recuerda que cada compilador necesitará su versión:

```
std::string nombre(const std::type_info &id)
{
    auto name = id.name();
    int status = 0;

    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> res {
        abi::__cxa_demangle(name, NULL, NULL, &status),
        std::free
    };

    return ((status == 0) ? res.get() : name);
}
```

Todo el código adicional es para hacerse cargo de la memoria devuelta por el desmutilador, esta función puede usarse así:

```
std::cout << "El tipo de g->v[i] es: " << nombre(typeid(g->v[i]));
```